# Razor pages don't read my css style files unless i give it the full physical path

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Iam trying to apply some css style to my razor page (in a ASP.NET project), when i type the path like that :

```
<link href="~\css\styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

It doesn't recognize the file path or apply any style.
but when i pass the full physical path like that :

```
<link href="E:\Development\etc...\css\styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

it reads the path and apply the style with no issue.
what could possibly go wrong, or what am I missing and don't understand?

Small notes :
1- When I add embedded Style to the page it works too.
2- Am trying to generate this page as a "pdf" file, but I don't think it matters/relevant to the way I add style.

Comment: maybe its the "\" try <link href="~/css/styles.css"

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work either.

Comment: Do you mean the page work well, but the generated pdf file not work well?

Comment: make sure the "css" folder (and styles.css file) exists in Visual Studio under the special "wwwroot" folder.  This is where all linked resources should be.  When making changes to the .css file, be aware that the browser can be pretty stubborn about caching the old file.  Press Ctrl-F5 in the browser to force a re-load.

Comment: I've put them in "wwwroot" folder already, but for some reason it the "cshtml" file doesn't feel/read the path or apply the style (unless i type the full physical path as i've explained above).

Comment: I suggest you could try to use F12's network to check the CSS file's path to see why the CSS find why it not working.